# Xamarin Linking in Release mode with Proguard

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, proguard, xamarin-linker

I'm working on a **Xamarin Forms** app for Android and iOS. We use a third-party SDK that comes as an `.aar` package, build action set to `LibraryProjectZip`. Then, we have calls from the forms, the iOS, and the Android parts of the code. Linking works just fine in debug mode if I remember correctly.

I'm failing to get the `Linker+ProGuard` work together. I've read for days and experimented with numerous solutions. I was having `java codes 1 and 2` - so I updated ProGuard and it started working. Then Linking was producing errors - `UnauthorizedAccessException` so I had to go to the respective folder and remove the `ReadOnly` permission. Then the project is built successfully but the app functionality is lost even though it runs and in `Device Log` I can see that some classes are missing.

To fix that, I created a `ProGuard.cfg` and added most of the assemblies that were crashing with the `"-keep"` command. However, I can't seem to find a way to preserve the functionality from this `.aar` package

Any suggestions?

I'm using VS 2017 and Xamarin 7.4 on Windows 10 with JDK  1.8, running as Administrator. Tried linking `Sdk Assemblies / User&Sdk Assemblies`. `Multidex` is on. I've tried putting the names of the assemblies of all the projects in the Skip Linking Assemblies field, no results. In the device log, I get a package name for the call that is failing so I tried adding this to ProGuard too but it didn't help. (it looked like `"-keep class com.something.something"`)

Comment: actually what helped me was searching for a proguard config file which is a more general one, stopping the linker from deleting some commonly used Android libraries let's say...combined with some of the things I found by looking at the errors, I got it working.

Comment: I know it might not be exactly a solution to the problem I originally mentioned but actually we are not using ProGuard anymore. This is not recommended by many people but in Xamarin it is not obfuscating code anyway and I needed it mainly for the app size reduction. However, after getting rid of the old architectures I was supporting - x86, armeabi and x86_64, the package was small enough.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, but this blog post may be of use.

"The Linker Analyzer is a command line tool that analyzes dependencies which are recorded during the LinkAssemblies step. It will show you what items were marked and resulted in the linked assembly."

https://www.jon-douglas.com/2017/09/22/linker-analyzer/